# Chrome video with transparent color overlay and blur shows a weird grid

Tags: css, html, video, opacity, blur

Some Macs with Chrome show a strange grid over the whole web page (screenshots below).
[Screenshot that shows the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdtS3.png)

Here is a very simple example where the client confirmed they see the grid on:
https://vanjajelic.com/clients/thedoor/index.html

As you can see, it's only a full screen HTML5 video with a div on top. The video has a blur on it and the div has an opacity and a background color (I can not put blur and color in the video as it changes dynamically). 
My conclusion is that the grid is obviously not part of the DOM as there is nothing in it to create it.

The only cause I can think of is, this is has to be a Chrome bug but wanted check if any of you experienced anything similar.

Note that the client was able to see the grid only on a few computers with this spec:
Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)
on
MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)
MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.5 (16F73)
Graphics Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB

I cannot reproduce it on my Mac nor on a number of PCs I run tests on :(

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW I also see it on a mid-2012 MacBook Air, Intel Graphics HD 4000, macOS 10.13.3 and the same version of Chrome (but not in Safari or Firefox). Also occurs in Brave (which uses the same engine). Have you tried with other videos? might be an encoding artefact of this one?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Yep, we see it on a number of videos. If I remove the blur and the background color from the div on top of it, the grid disappears, which tells me it's not the encoding.

Comment: I also noticed this glitches. They appear on fullscreen viewing such as youtube video, VLC player movie, even user login screen. And the images I see on background are always some webpage, some youtube page or it could be a page without any possible video on it such as a GitLab. I'm using a Chrome.